# Cannot redeem USDT using Binance API in C#

Tags: c#, binance

While trying to redeem USDT from my binance account using `RedeemFlexibleProductAsync` method but I'm getting :

> 'Error: daily product not exist'

as result.

1. I can redeem the amount using the Binance App
2. I have checked on typo for string ProductId(which is "USDT")
3. The connection with the exchange server is successful
4. I can read all flexible balances from that connection, including USDT
5. I have enabled Trading and Withdrawal for my API
6. I have tried different receiveWindows, now it's set at maximum of 60000

Here is my code:

```
private async Task<bool> RedeemFromEarn(string coin,decimal redeemAmount)
        {
            var earn = await client.GeneralApi.Savings.GetFlexibleProductPositionAsync();
            var earnBalance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(earn.Data.First(x => x.Asset.Equals(coin)).TotalQuantity.ToString());
            if(Convert.ToDecimal(earnBalance) > redeemAmount)
            {
                var redeem = await client.GeneralApi.Savings.RedeemFlexibleProductAsync(coin, redeemAmount,RedeemType.Normal,60000);

                if (redeem.Success)
                {
                    Debug.Print($"Redeem successful. Transaction ID: {redeem.Data}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Print($"Error: {redeem.Error.Message}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Print($"Not enough {coin} in Earn, try redeeming max {earnBalance}");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem by examining the earn object. Binance expects USDT001 as productId parameter rather than assumed by me as USDT only. However, I had to modify the code above to post also the coin name (USDT) to get the balances from GetFlexibleProductPositionAsync()

Comment: You can either delete the Q if you don't think it will be useful for other users or if you do think others could beneifit from your findings, it is totally ok to answer your own question.